# how to hook all new processes in Windows

Tags: windows, dll, hook, monitor, dll-injection

I want to write a program to detach dll injection or vulnerability exploit by creating a monitor thread for all processes.I want to do this in user level instead of inserting a driver.

I try to use AppInit_DLLs to create a thread at DllMain,but it's not work if a program don't load user32.dll.

I try to listen a new process creation event and suspend new process for loading my monitor dll,but it's not work well.

Is there any methods to hook all new processes before they start run?

Answer (score 5):

Most programs are run via double click so explorer.exe is the process which uses CreateProcess to launch them

Hook explorer.exe and make CreateProcess and ShellExecute/Ex hook the created processes also and so on

You can do some more by hooking all the running processes with the same technique once your injector opens thus you absolutely are hooking all user mode processes

Make sure to have the proper rights if you aren't running as admin you won't be able to hook processes running as admin

The functions you need to hook are usually CreateProcess NtCreateProcess ShellExecuteInfo/Ex

You will be using NtSuspendProcess and NtResumeProcess to set your hooks before the process has a chance to defend itself but tls callbacks may be already called , and in case of NtCreateProcess , CreateProcess you can use CREATE_SUSPENDED then ResumeThread with the thread handle you get from the function

if you want to go deeper you can hook NtCrateFile as any attempt to execute exe or load a dll will need to open the file to allocate the image in the memory

Comment: I think this may be a good suggestion,I can inject all user processes by traversing all existing processes,then hook CreateProcess to inject new processe.Thus,I can hook all new processes.

Comment: And thanks for answering my old question about explorer.exe . The reason it is the parent of most processes is that when you double click on a file exe or another extension windows will make a message to operate on this file and the windows shell (explorer by default and you can change it) always processes this message queue so it will execute it if it is exe or look in registry to find a program to open this file format (notepad for txt , word for doc/docx) .the same thing happens for copying files and cutting or deleting them you will notice that these actions are performed with explorer

Comment: I think you should post these under target answer :) .I'd like to discuss this in that question.And,thanks for you help.